Resampling from daily to hourly data not working on last date
I am trying to convert daily data to hourly data by resampling the observed daily value for each hour in the day. The method I have works, except on the last date. I will give a reproducible example. Suppose we have the following data:
T1 = pd.Timestamp("2024-01-01")
T2 = pd.Timestamp("2024-01-02")
df = pd.DataFrame({"T" : [T1,T2], "V" : [1,2]})

Now resampling hourly and filling:
df = (df 
        .set_index("T")
        .resample("h")
        .ffill())

This propagates and fills the value 1 for each hour in T1, but not T2. I was expecting a dataframe of length 48, but received a dataframe of length 25.This behaviour repeats for more dates i.e. it works for every date except the last one.
I don't know why this is happening. I have tried playing with the various keyword argument in resample, but none worked for me.
Thanks in advance.

Forward fill will add values from the first to the last timestamp included in the index.
When you resample with a hourly frequency, pandas will convert 2024-01-02 to a datetime with time at midnight. There will be 24 records from the first date, and just 1 record for the last date.
You can use a workaround, and add an additional date to your DataFrame, so that you will get all 24 hours for date T2. I also added an additional dropna() at the end, so that the final result won't contain this dummy date.
T1 = pd.Timestamp("2024-01-01")
T2 = pd.Timestamp("2024-01-02")
T3 = pd.Timestamp("2024-01-03") # Create one record that will hold an 
empty value
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "T" : [T1,T2, T3],
        "V" : [1,2, pd.NA] # Add a null value here
    }
)

df = (df 
    .set_index("T")
    .resample("h")
    .ffill()
    .dropna() # Remove the last value, since it's useless
 )

